# Scraping a web page with Java script using R

Tags: r, scrape

I am working on a task to get the details from a third party website using technique of data scrape using R.

On manual access,the site is authenticated by our sso of our organization and then it is directed to the relevant website pages.

Please advise if my approach is correct and how can I access the actual website and scrape the javascript contents of the actual website.

Below is the sample code

The first print command output is as follow

1] "This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for your request.
You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process. If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button below.https://xxxx.com/siteminderagent/SmMakeCookie.ccc?SMSESSION=QUERY&PERSIST=0&TARGET=$SM$http%3a%2f%2falacrity%2e%2ecom%3a8084%2falacrity%2fSecure%2fAlacrityLogin%2ejsp\">\r\n"
attr(,"Content-Type")
                  charset 
 "text/html" "iso-8859-1"

The second print method gives the error
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to myscrapeapp

```
library(RCurl)

#Set the  browsing links 
loginurl = "http://sso.something.com"
dataurl  = "https://myscrapeapp:8084/uview"

pars=list(
  username =myusername,
  password=mypassword
  )

 agent="Firefox/38.2.0" 

 curl= getCurlHandle()

 #post the login information

 html=postForm(loginurl, .params = pars, curl=curl)

 print(html) 
 html=getURL(dataurl, curl=curl)

 print(html)
```

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html and even though you are using a legit SSO login, be sure scraping is allowed by JPM Chase (they have some good tech to catch scraping even with pass-through auth).

Comment: this might help or be easier? https://github.com/hadley/rvest